# Progress bar to display progress in terms of corresponding textview?

Tags: android

So I'm working on this game idea and I think it would be really cool to have a progress bar as the XP bar. So I have a textView that shows how much XP you have and I want to Progress bar to increase as you get more XP and then Reset and increase the amount after the player level ups.

I have no idea how to use any of this and I was hoping to get a few tips....

Any ideas?

Comment: What is this XP...Please XPlain?

Comment: You could just use setProgress(XP).